# Requests to servlet wait in queue

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency, glassfish, threadpool

I am developing web app build in GWT using GWT RCP. Application is designed for instant messaging which I use redis messaging for.

When waiting in servlete on a message and I am subscribe on that channel in redise everything works   as planned. Though when number of awaiting requests on server is more than 5, the 6th request doesn't start to be processed and waits in que until one of the previous requests is processed. I wasn't sure if the problem is in redis (I am using jedis library) therefore I tried to call directly sleep on currentThread but it behaved the same.

```
public class TestServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
            TestService {

    @Override   
    public void syncWait(Date time) {
        try{
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000l);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().error("sleep error", e);
        }
        return ;
    }
}
```

It's not just about one particular servlet, when 5 requests are opened, 6th doesn't even load static content. I tried it on jety, glassfish and tomcat.

I also tried to change settings of threadpool in glassfish, maxthread-count I set up on 200 but it didn't work.

Could you please advice on how to increase the number of requests processed pers session and per server?

Answer (score 0):

For this you REALLY want to use one of the servlet Comet implementations and an NIO connector. I'm not intimately familiar with Glassfish or Jetty, but on Tomcat you can use a combination of APR (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html) and advanced IO (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html) to do what you want.

Please note that using Tomcat's Advanced IO is more complicated (and less well documented) than the standard Servlet 2.5 api.

Resin, Tomcat 7 and Glassfish (I believe) support the Servlet 3.0 spec which also offers support for similar features: you may want to take a look at that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure if i want Comet and NIO. Comet is for handling concurent requests. I don't need to handle concurrent requests, I just problem with start processing requests when server has 5 connections opened. Is Comet solution for this?

Comment: Typically calling `sleep` on threads in a Servlet is a bad idea: if you are going to have multiple requests idle then you will want Comet and NIO. As far as more than 5 connections are concerned you must have a configuration flaw somewhere, as you should definitely be able to handle more than 5 connections.